# Displaying Messages Without Using Alerts

Tags: javascript

I am working on a "guess my number" game and have ran into a problem. My game is supposed to select a random integer between 1 and 10 and allow the user to guess until they guess the correct number. After each guess, I'm supposed to display a message telling whether their guess was too high, too low, correct, or if they'd guessed that number before. I had the game working (except for displaying the array of previously guessed numbers) by using alerts to display the whether the user was too high, low, correct, etc like this.

```
if (guess == this.num) {
    alert("Correct! It took you " + turns " tries to guess my number.");
    ...
}
```

However, going back over the directions I see that we are not supposed to user alerts or any other kinds of pop-ups. So I need to figure out how to display these messages on the screen rather than in an alert box.

Here is how I've attempted to do this without the use of alerts, but now the game is not working at all (nothing happens when I click either of the buttons):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>Guess My Number</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tries = [];
            var game = {
                num : 0,
                turns : 1,
                reset : function() {
                    this.turns = 1;
                    this.newNum();
                },
                newNum : function() {
                    this.num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) +1;
                },
                guessNumber : function(guess) {
                    try {
                        guess = parseInt(guess);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        alert("Enter a guess!");
                        this.turns++;
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (guess == this.num) {
                        document.getElementById("result").value = "Correct! It took you " + this.turns + " tries to guess my number.");
                        alert("Correct! It took you " + this.turns + " turns to guess my number.");
                        tries.push(guess);
                        document.querySelector("#tries").textContent = tries.join(', ');
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(guess > this.num) {
                        document.getElementById("result").value = "Your guess is too high. Try again.";
                        alert("Your guess is too high. Try again.");
                        document.querySelector("#tries").textContent = tries.join(', ');
                        this.turns++;
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return false;
                    }

                    else if(tries.indexOf(guess) != -1) {
                        document.getElementById("result").value = "You have already guessed this number. Try again.";
                        this.turns++;
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("result").value = "Your guess is too low. Try again.";
                        document.querySelector("#tries").textContent = tries.join(', ');
                        tries.push(guess);
                        this.turns++;
                        document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };

            function guessNumber() {
                var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
                game.guessNumber(guess);
                document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
            }

            function resetGame() {
                game.reset();
                document.getElementById("guess").value = " ";
            }

            resetGame();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Would You Like To Play A Game?</h1>
        <h2>Thank you for checking out my game. Good luck!</h2>
        <h3>Created by Beth Tanner</h3>
        <h2>Directions:</h2>
        <p>
            The game is very simple. I am thinking of a number between 1
            and 10. It is your job to guess that number. If you do not guess
            correctly on your first attempt, don't worry, you can keep guessing 
            until you guess the correct number.
        </p>
        <p>
            Your Guess: <input type="text" id="guess" size="10" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Sumbit Guess" onclick="guessNumber()" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset Game" onclick="resetGame()"/>
        </p>
        <h3>How Did You Do?:</h3>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" id="result" size="20" />
        </p>
        <h3>Here Are Your Guesses So Far:</h3
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any simple way to do this. I want the messages to display in a hidden text filed below the heading "How did you do?:" if that makes it a little clearer.

Here is a jsfiddle I made with my most recent code, http://jsfiddle.net/3p3f86fj/6/

Comment: ... "to display in a hidden text field" ... that seems problematic

Comment: See Leeish answer ... then look at your javascript console; you should see an error there. User your web browser's Developer Tools or get Firebug or something similar.  You ought to be able to change all of your `alert(...something...)` calls to `myDisplayFunction(...something...)` calls, then work one just that function, along the lines that ZekeDroid suggested.

Comment: Maybe that's not the best way to word it. I just mean I don't want it to look like there's anything there until the user enters a guess, and then the corresponding message would be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a div to your body with a unique ID, like `<div id='result'></div>` and then in your JS, reference it by getting the document by ID and your functions should change the text of the div to whatever you need it to be. Make a function to change the name if you want to abstract some of the logic away.

Comment: Something like <div id="result"> <input type="hidden" id="result" size="20"</div> and in JS something like document.getElementById("result").value = "guessNumber"; ?

Comment: Oh wait, but then how would it know what message to display?

Comment: You're setting it right? Whenever JS calls on your div object, after manipulation it will automatically appear updated so when at any point you say document.getElementById("result").value = "some string", it will autotmatically change.

Comment: Oh ok, so rather than saying value ="guessNumber";, I'd have the value as whatever message pertains to that guess? Like document.getElementById("result") value ="Correct!";

Comment: Exactly. I suggest making a jSfiddle out of it and post it so we can help you even more specifically

Comment: This will essentially work. Do you know why it doesn't? Have you tried debugging and going step by step into your function call? Try opening the console (F12 in chrome) and see for yourself. You're making a call to guessNumber() from your HTML code which isn't recognized. Most likely because that is a function of your "game" variable so you'd need game.guessNumber(). But that won't work either cause "game" isn't defined. You should play around with console.log() lines with your code and using the console. If you want to get fancier, write the line "debugger();"

Comment: How would I go about defining "game"?

Comment: it's bad practice but make it global, don't put a var in front of it. then there are other bugs in your code but debug through it and it'll work. as far as this question is concerned, it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

It's broken because of this line I believe:

`document.getElementById("result").value = "Correct! It took you " + this.turns + " tries to guess my number.");`

You have a stray `)` at the end.

I'm looking into other issues I see now.